# Rails saving empty values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I Have the following models

Users
name
code

Registers
user
hour

I want to add Registers by user code so I did this

Controller

```
    def create

    usuario = User.find_by_code(params[:code])
    hora = params[:hour]
    @register = Register.new( :user => usuario ,  :hour => hora )
    if @register.save
        redirect_to action: "index"
    else
        render "new"
    end
```

View

```
<%= form_for @user do |u| %>
Name: <%= u.text_field :name %>
Code: <%= u.text_field :code %>
<%= u.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Model

```
class Register < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor   :code
belongs_to :user
end
```

Any ways it adds new register but all are empty

Comment: I'm not sure, the code, name and hour are models or attributes?

Comment: why do you need `attr_accessor   :code` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you must to add the `usuario_params` method as private:

```
....
private

def usuario_params
  params.require(:usuario).permit(:hour, :code)
end
```

And now you can access the `usuario_params` in yours methods:

```
def create
  usuario = User.find_by_code(usuario_params[:code])
  hora = usuario_params[:hour]
  @register = Register.new(user: usuario, hour: hora)

  if @register.save
    redirect_to action: "index"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked for me and I had another issue when listing on Index.

Comment: Guilherme, please click the tick beside this answer to accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`code` looks like model field, so do not overload it with `attr_accessor`

Also from form it will come in `params[:user][:code]`